# MSSQL SP: Select all rows from one table using IDs from another

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Perhaps quite a simple question, that seems to have a rather complicated answer that I have not been able to dig out.

Im using an SQL-server 2012.

I have these two statements, that selects all my data based on a parameter, and then also selects up to five rows of data (which means no joins) from another table based on the IDs gotten from the first select.

```
SELECT * FROM TBL1 WHERE XXX
SELECT * FROM TBL2
    WHERE TBL1_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TBL1 WHERE XXX)
```

It seems very redundant to me, that I basicly have to repeat my TBL1 select in my TBL2, and instead I would like to know if I can select from TBL2 using the ID's from the * data I got from TBL1.

I am fully aware that this will most likely result in two resultsets that dont necessarily correlate, but I can generally use PHP array-manipulation to fix this so its not that big of a deal.

Comment: It may look redundant, but any other way will be only way more complex. Unless you want to join them together and select the data from TBL1 together with the data of TBL2, retrieving one dataset instead of two.

Comment: @HoneyBadger It may be more complex, but sometimes I may be selecting anywhere from 0 to 10.000 rows, which means three selects would be quite draining as compared to only two I would believe.

If you are scratching your head about "Why would he select 10.000 rows and be new to SP's", my current task at work has me writing SPs to show a company that should write the SP's for us how we want the SP's to work

Comment: In this case, more complex will in all likelihood also mean less performant, less secure and/or downright dangerous. I don't quite follow why you have to do performance tuning if it's just to show the people who are going to build the SP what results it should give, surely that's their job. Also, 10.000 rows is not much, in database terms, I wouldn't worry about that.

Comment: aight @HoneyBadger, thanks for your consideration and time with my question, I will stick to this way then and see where that leads the project

Answer (score 0):

Using `IN`:

```
Declare @T1 table (ID INT , Value VARCHAR(50) );
Declare @T2 table (ID INT);

INSERT INTO @T1 Values (1,'First') , (2,'Second');
INSERT INTO @T2 Values (1),(3);

SELECT * FROM @T1 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM @T2);
```

Resault :

```
ID          Value
----------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           First
```

Using `INNER JOIN` :

```
SELECT T1.ID , T1.Value FROM @T1 T1 INNER JOIN @T2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID;
```

Resault:

```
ID          Value
----------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           First
```

Using `LEFT JOIN` :

```
SELECT T1.ID , T1.Value FROM @T1 T1 LEFT JOIN @T2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID 
WHERE T2.ID IS NOT NULL;
```

Resault :

```
ID          Value
----------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           First
```

Comment: That is exactly how I wrote my own version... There is no difference in yours and mine

Answer (score 0):

You also use EXISTS

```
SELECT * FROM TBL2
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TBL1 WHERE TBL1.ID = TBL2.TBL1_ID AND XXX)
```